# Fahrenheit to Celsius java craches with decimals

Tags: java

I asked this question a while ago and was sent to a question that dont realy answer my question. Problem is that the program works with whole numbers (80f, 40f 60f) etc but crashes once I try decimal numbers (80.5f, 40.5,f 60.5f). I'm new to this, so it may very well be that the answer I was sent to realy does answer my question but I'm not good enough to get it.

```
import java.util.*;

class temperaturen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);      

        System.out.println("Enter temperatue in Fahrenheit");
        double number = in.nextInt();
        number = ((number - 32)/1.8);

        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using in.nextInt() - so the scanner will only accept integers and not doubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Problem is that the program works with whole numbers`

because

`nextInt()` - Scans the next token of the input as an int.
So when you provide a double as input the token does not match the Integer regular expression so it will throw `InputMismatchException`

So if better use `nextDouble()` instead

Answer (score 2):

Use `in.nextDouble()` instead of `in.nextInt()`

To further make your program robust enough to handle errors, you can try `Exception Handling`
Then, your code segment would look like :

```
try {
     double number = in.nextDouble();
     number = ((number - 32)/1.8);  
        } 
catch (InputMismatchException X) {
     System.out.println("A Numerical Value is expected!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You retrieve a double with nextInt() so no wonder why your program throws an Exception (probably a NumberFormatException). Use nextDouble instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using in.nextDouble() instead of in.nextInt() you can get rid of the error.